# After signing into Twitter Mobile using Web Intents, URL converts spaces to plus signs (%2520)

Tags: mobile, twitter, urlencode, url-encoding

I've been working with Web Intents to provide simple Tweet capabilities via the user's default mobile device. However, if the user is not currently signed into Mobile Twitter and accesses the tweet URL for the first time, upon signing in they will be taken to the compose page but all spaces in the precomposed Tweet (%20) are converted to + symbols (%2520).

Example URL:

```
https://mobile.twitter.com/compose/tweet?status=Word1%20Word%20Word3
```

If you are already signed in and subsequently visit that URL, everything is fine. It's only the first time the user signs in, the %20 is converted to %2520 and appears on the page as "Word1+Word2+Word3". Any thoughts? This happens on all browsers and platforms I have tested.

Answer (score 0):

I think Twitter have a new API for this kind of links. Try this: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button

Example:

```
https://twitter.com/share?url=&text=Word1%20Word%20Word3
```